# context is not defined JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, templates, handlebars.js

So referring to the original problem I have here [Google Maps Javascript V3 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20302497/google-maps-javascript-v3-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-offsetwidth) and after doing a lot of googling, I have found a solution which I thought would be workable which is this [How to append multiple Google Maps areas to divs using Handlebars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10006898/how-to-append-multiple-google-maps-areas-to-divs-using-handlebars).

However, I have implemented mine in the following way

```
var EmployeeView = function(employee){
  this.render = function(){
    $('body').append(this.el);
      // inside the new div, put the Handlebars template, with the data from the employee
      this.el.html(EmployeeView.template(employee)).ready( function() {
        var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
          zoom: 8
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);
      });
      return this;
    };

    this.initialize = function(){
      this.el=$("</div>");
      window.localStorage.removeItem('paramId');
      console.log('removed');
      window.localStorage.setItem('paramId',employee);
      console.log('added ' + employee.id);    
    };
    this.initialize();
  }

EmployeeView.template = Handlebars.compile($("#employee-tpl").html());
```

Not sure if thats the right way of 'referring' to that solution but now, whenever I run the page, the following error is thrown `Uncaught ReferenceError: context is not defined`

Anyone got any ideas? and to add, my html is as follows

```
<body>
<script id="employee-tpl" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  <div class='details'>
    <img class='employee-image' src='img/{{firstName}}_{{lastName}}.jpg' />
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#map/{{this.id}}">See on map</a></li>         
      <li>Share with friends</li>
      <li><div id="map-canvas"/></li>
    </ul>
  <script src="lib/iscroll.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/handlebars.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/storage/cafe-memory-store.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?APIKEY&sensor=true"></script> 
  <script src="js/MapView.js"></script>
  <script src="js/EmployeeView.js"></script>
  <script src="js/HomeView.js"></script>
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: It means that the variable `context` is undefined: is it the `HTMLtemplate(context)` function defined as well? Otherwise it should be `EmployeeView.template` in that place I guess.

Comment: but referring to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10006898/how-to-append-multiple-google-maps-areas-to-divs-using-handlebars it doesn't seem like HTMLTemplate and `context` is extra defined though? please correct me :(

Comment: I can see them defined in the code snippet in the page.

Answer (score 2):

In this line:

```
$("employee-tpl").append(HTMLtemplate(context))
```

You are passing an `undefined` function and one `undefined` variable (`context`).
`context` should contain he `id` parameter you defined in your HandlebarJS template to be replaced

```
<a href="#map/{{this.id}}">See on map</a>
```

`HTMLTemplate` in your case is `EmployeeView.template` which holds the HandlebarJS compiled template: it is a function that receives as arguments the `context` variable ( or maybe the `employee` variable?)

If I got it right your code should be:

```
var EmployeeView = function(employee){

  this.render = function(){
    $('body').append(this.el);
    // inside the new div, put the Handlebars template, with the data from the employee
    this.el.html(EmployeeView.template(employee))).ready( function() {
        var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
        zoom: 8

        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);
    });


    return this;
  };



  this.initialize = function(){
    this.el=.$("</div>");
    window.localStorage.removeItem('paramId');
    console.log('removed');
    window.localStorage.setItem('paramId',employee);
    console.log('added ' + employee.id);    
  };
  this.initialize();


}

EmployeeView.template = Handlebars.compile($("#employee-tpl").html());
```

I think you have to pass `employee` to the template because I saw `first_name` and `last_name` in the template.

Comment: Hi Marco, i have updated my code as above, however, it is now throwing another error `Uncaught ReferenceError: employee is not defined `

Comment: Following your advice @marcocl, it now throws `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of null ` and i understand that this is due to div not rendered at the time this function is called\

Comment: It doesn't find the element to append your template: I've updated the answer. ;)

Comment: Hi Marco, thanks very much for your answer, however it is still throwing the same error. I have updated in the above question