# document.getElementById(#mapid) returns null

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates, dom, handlebars.js

referring to this question here, [context is not defined javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20373278/context-is-not-defined-javascript)

I am just throwing out another question in regards of the error where document.getElementById is returning a null even though the template is already compiled.

A brief background, I am using handlebar template, jquery and I want a googlemap to appear in 1 of the handlebar template.

my html:

```
 <script id="employee-tpl" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
<div class='header'><a href='#' class="button header-button header-button-left">Back</a><h1>Gloop</h1></div>
<div class='details'>
    <img class='employee-image' src='img/{{firstName}}_{{lastName}}.jpg' />
    <h1>{{name}}</h1>
    <h2>{{address}}</h2>
    <h2><a href="tel:{{phone}}">{{phone}}</a></h2>
    <span class="location"></span>
    <ul>
        <li><div id="map-canvas"> </div></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</script>
```

and my js

```
this.render = function(){

    this.el.html(EmployeeView.template(employee));
console.log(document.getElementById("map-canvas"));

};
this.initialize = function(){
    this.el=$('<div/>');

};

this.initialize();
}

EmployeeView.template = Handlebars.compile($("#employee-tpl").html());
```

notice that the call to console will log a `null` value and this js is called at the bottom of my html file

```
<script src="lib/iscroll.js"></script>
<script src="lib/handlebars.js"></script>
<script src="lib/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/storage/cafe-memory-store.js"></script>
<script src="js/EmployeeView.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

my understanding it that the my compilation will render the div which then should be able to be seen but this is not the case. Anyone knows why?

Comment: Looks like invalid markup to me, a DIV is not a self closing element ?

Comment: hi adeno, hmm it doesn't make a difference though whether its a self close or using an end tag

Comment: If `getElementById` is returning `null`, it's because there is no element with that `id` in the DOM *when you call it*. Use your browser's DOM utilities and debugger to find out why. Put a breakpoint in your `render` function and look at the DOM at that moment in time.

Comment: This one is not correct: `<li><div id="map-canvas"/></`

Comment: thanks for the tip crowder, however using chrome and elements tab doesn't show the div and i'm thinking because this is part of a the handlebar template/script ?

Comment: @AntoJurkovic i corrected already, but the issue persists

Comment: This line `<script id="employee-tpl" type="text/x-handlebars-template">` has no closing `</script>` or it is missing just here?

Comment: @AntoJurkovic updated my answer to show that

Answer (score 0):

Is that fiddle all the code you have? If I add this to the JS it works.. but it's hard to see what you're after.

```
var source = $("#employee-tpl").html(); 
var template = Handlebars.compile(source); 
var data = { //your data here }
$('body').append(template(data));
```

Comment: sadly no, its still returning a null :(

Comment: Are you closing the <script> tag? Any chance you could create a fiddle of your code?

Comment: where do i put in the snippet you have added here? Perhaps you can put it in the fiddle and i will grab from there?